# Searching NYT API using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am writing code in Angular JS  implement a standard application which would show a search field and a search button the screen and when a search is run, it should pull in the remote result and display them on the screen
Console is not showing any errors to me but i cant get to display the results on the screen.I am wondering how do i display the results on the screen

here is the code in my js file

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

      var clearError = function(result) {
        $scope.error = "";
        return result;
      };

      var applyData = function(result) {
        $scope.articles = result.data;
        console.log(result.data);
      };

      var rejected = function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.message;
      };

      var getArticles = function() {
        var url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=North+Korea&api-key=052861d142cf4eb7fa12bb79781fdbe1:11:69591426";
        var promise = $http({
          method: 'GET',
          // https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com
          url: "https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url)
        });

        promise.success(clearError).then(applyData);
        promise.error(function(error) {
          $scope.error = error.message;
        });
      };
      getArticles();

      $scope.getRepos = _.debounce(getArticles, 300);

    }]);
```

And here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-keyup="getArticles()" />
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Headline</td>
        <td>Body</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-bind="error" style="color:red;"></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="a in Articles">
        <td>{{a.headline}}</td>
        <td>{{a.body}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is status of request in browser console network tab? Do you get results?

Comment: In the network tab it says 52 requests | 448 kb transferred | 7.16s

Comment: need to look at your specific api request and see what it returns

Comment: all the files are available on my plunker here http://plnkr.co/users/matif84 in nytapi

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.

In scope you have `articles` but in html it is `Articles`.

To access the actual data you want in response you need to look deeper inside the data object returned:

Try changing:

```
var applyData = function(result) {
    $scope.articles = result.data;
    console.log(result.data);
  };
```

To:

```
 var applyData = function(result) {
    var articles=result.data.response.docs
    $scope.articles = articles;
    console.log(articles);
  };
```

Then in the html you need slightly different properties since `headline` has sub properties like `main` and `print_headline`

As example

```
  <tr ng-repeat="a in articles">
    <td>{{a.headline.main}}</td>
    <td>{{a.lead_paragraph}}</td>
  </tr>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzHKXF?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks .When i implement the code you suggested and make all the A's in Articles the same case it starts giving results on the query term used in the URL link but i am still figuring out how to search any term using the search button

Comment: will need to remove the hard code North Korea stuff and replace with dynamic term